How do I get the information for an HTML element via VBA and the web browser control?
I have a question. I have a webbrowsercontrol and want to read different data from a webpage via vba.
The data is as follows:
<article class="messagexyz " data-author="mrjemand" data-content="something" id="1305195" ...

Using the following code:
For Each All In ebform!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementsByTagName("article")

I get my elements. But how do I get the information from data-author,data-content and id. Unfortunately I cannot find the appropriate program code.
Thank you very much !
I tried it with getAttribute and getProperty because I couldn't come up with anything sensible.

Always helps to show the code you tried, or at least more than a single line.  How exactly did you use getAttribute and what happened when you tried that?

For example:
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim art
    
    Me.web.Navigate "about:blank" ' `web` is a web browser control
    Do While Me.web.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    With Me.web.Document
        .Open
        'create some article content 
        .Write "<article class='messagexyz' data-author='mrjemand' data-content='something' id='1305195'>Article here</article>"
        .Write "<article class='messageabc' data-author='Jim' data-content='blah' id='1305196'>Article2 here</article>"
        .Close
    End With
    'loop each article
    For Each art In Me.web.Document.getElementsByTagName("article")
        Debug.Print art.innerHTML
        'list some attributes
        Debug.Print , art.getAttribute("data-author")
        Debug.Print , art.getAttribute("class")
        Debug.Print , art.getAttribute("data-content")
    Next art
    
End Sub

output:
Article here
              mrjemand
              messagexyz
              something
Article2 here
              Jim
              messageabc
              blah

